# Проблема подключения к интернету android

Tags: android

Ребят помогите разобраться имею код:

```
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // получаем данные с внешнего ресурса
            try {
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                resultJson = buffer.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return resultJson;
        }
```

На выходе получаю ошибку е:`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertPathValidatorException: Could not validate certificate: current time: Fri Aug 26 19:00:57 GMT+03:00 2016, validation time: Thu Jun 15 13:22:45 GMT+03:00 2017`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас разбежка времени между клиентом и сервером. Выставьте корректное время и проблема исчезнет.